# How to Open workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that used to work nicely for a while.
I replaced seemingly irrelevant function `Insert Picture` for `Add Shape Picture` in different Sub and all sudden. It stopped working with error `1004` on line `3`.

Can you advise what I have wrong there, please?

```vb
Public Sub CopyData()
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C:Z").Clear

  Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book1.xlsx"

  Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z200").Copy

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C1").PasteSpecial

  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure that `Book1.xlsx` exists in the path and is accessible? set a breakpoint at the `Open`-statement, then run the code and when it stops, enter `? Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book1.xlsx")` in the immediate window. Does it return something?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Thanks to your suggestion of using immediate window I somehow got message that the target sheet for Paste was procted (locked). It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The targeted sheet for Paste function was protected (locked). It works now.